# Map usertype from query and return response laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
$user = User::select('user_id', 'name', 'email', 'username', 'type')
                  ->where('name', '=', $name)
                  ->where('active', 1)
                  ->first();
```

It will return first record. But what else if we have 4 records.

Mean there are four records in database with same name But i would like to display that whose type == 6 if type is not equal 6 then it should take first();

How this possible please guide

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the Rwd code try this code

```
$query = User::select('user_id', 'name', 'email', 'username', 'type')
                ->where('name', '=', $name)
                ->where('active', 1);

            $users = $query->where('type', 6)->get();

            if (!$users->isEmpty()) {
                $user =  $query->first();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks G2 for you response, But not working as i expect